# CSS issue with both jQuery and Knockout validations plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, knockout.js

**Problem**:CSS is not getting changed when validation are fired

**Scenario**: In my project I am using jQuery validations and knockout validation.
In knockout I am having a parent model binding and child model that are dynamically generated on button click event.

**validations**:for parent model binding i have jQuery validations(model validations are used) but for child model I am having knockout validations(as property is not mentioned in the model)

problem:Validation message are getting displayed but css error class is not getting bind.For knockout validation I have mentioned

```
 ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: false,
    decorateElement: true,        
    errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error',
    errorMessageClass: 'field-validation-error'
});
```

knockout version:knockout:3.0.0

Comment: could you give some more code regarding your parent-child view models and jQuery validations?  The thing that does work, is that related to KO or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration **errorMessageClass** is neglected when the **insertMessages** is set to ***false***.

I suspect you are using a custom error message element in the View. Then you can use this method ***notValidField*** bound to the ***visible*** keyword.

```
<span data-bind="visible: notValidField(searchCriteria.nsn, canShowErrors()),
 text: valMsg" class="error"></span>
```

and its implementation is something like this:

```
notValidField = function (boundField, canShowErrors) {
    return boundField.isModified() && !boundField.isValid() && canShowErrors;
};
```

Note that the "***canShowErrors***" flag is for viewing validation errors on submit, if you want realtime validation,  remove this flag.

Give it a try.